# EntityFramework not saving new data on entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a question regarding updating existing users with new data using EntityFramework and Domain Models. Or actually more like an issue.

When Adding a new Order to a User, after converting said `Order` to an `OrderEntity` then adding it to the `UserEntity`, and persisting it to the Database, the given Order is not saved.

So we have an `IUserModel` here:

```
public interface IUser
{
     int ID { get; }
     List<IOrder> Orders { get; }
}
```

And an entity `UserEntity` here:

```
public class UserEntity
{
     int ID { get; set; }
     public List<OrderEntity> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

We have a service called `PersistenceService` here:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateInformation(IUser user)
{
     using (var databaseContext = new DatabaseContext())
     {
         var userEntity = await database.Users.Include(u => u.Orders)
                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID == user.ID);

         userEntity.Orders = user.Orders.ToEntity(); // Extension (convert to entity)         
         databaseContext.Entry(userEntity).State 
                      = EntityState.Modified; // Do we need this?
         databaseContext.Entry(userEntity.Orders).State 
                      = EntityState.Modified; // Do we need this?

         await databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
}
```

Tables in the Database look like this:

```
Orders                                      User
--------                                    --------
int ID                                      int ID
Money Price 
int UserId -- foreign key to user that owns this order
```

**Edit:** 
At some point when a user wants to create an Order we call do this:

```
public async void AddNewOrder(IOrder order)
{
    IUser user = GetActiveUser(); // This just return an IUser
    var persistenceService = GetPersistenceService(); // returns instance of persistence service

    user.Orders.Add(order);
    await persistenceService.UpdateInformation(user);
}
```

**Edit 09-11-2016:**
After more debugging, it looks like the line:

```
await persistenceService.UpdateInformation(user);
```

Never returns, this doesn't change when you change the code to run synchronously either. So it's no threading problem.

Comment: How are you calling this method? You need to give it time for SaveChangesAsync to work. Have you tried UpdateInformation().GetAwaiter().GetResult()?

Comment: As DavidG said, you seem to be merely updating an order, not associating it with the user.

Comment: Alright -- so I did an edit to show how an order is added to the user, also @RicardoPeres doesn't help, the issue is not solved by doing synchronous work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the orders list in this statement:

```
userEntity.Orders = user.Orders.ToEntity(); // Extension (convert to entity)
```

I'm pretty sure that's what messes stuff up. If you change the line to:

```
userEntity.Orders.AddRange(user.Orders.ToEntity());
```

I believe it should work. This does however always add the all the orders to the customer as new. If this is not what you want, you can use a combination of Add and Remove calls to update the Orders collection instead of just adding them. But to just test if it saves anything you can just use AddRange() for now.

In addition, you shouldn't set the State of the entities unless you're attaching them (which you aren't). So drop these lines

```
     databaseContext.Entry(userEntity).State 
                  = EntityState.Modified; // Do we need this?
     databaseContext.Entry(userEntity.Orders).State 
                  = EntityState.Modified; // Do we need this?
```

Comment: I don't think so, this also duplicates the entries already in Orders - right?

Comment: In that case a simple AddRange may not suffice, and a somewhat more complex sync mechanism may be required, but I do think that overwriting the Orders property is what's causing your problem. Just add the new values, update the existing and remove the removed. I'm pretty sure it'll work then. If you do the AddRange first you'll get duplicates, but it's an easy way to see if the Orders are saved at all.

Comment: Hey @Robba, I tried your solution but that didn't help either, no change.
The issue is that databaseContext.SaveChanges(); never returns

Comment: Come to think of it, you don't need to set the State() of the entity to Modified. This is only needed in special cases. For now, just drop the State() lines and update the .Orders collection like I mentioned before. (I'll edit the anser too)

Comment: Okay - turns out you were right and we need to .AddRange() However, I'm not sure I understand why we need to AddRange, instead of just replacing the list with a new one, should this not work too? Or is the List of Orders special someway and by replacing it we remove some link or state?
I am going ahead and doing a "merge/update" method so that I don't get duplicates. Thanks, marking as answer.

Comment: Yes, EntityFramework creates proxies for your classes and tracks what happens to the contents of the collections. When you add something, the added entity is added to the internal list of tracked entities and will thus be saved. If you overwrite the list, the tracking mechanism is lost.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that updating the User won't help. You need to force update the Orders that contain a reference to the user, IMO. Not add them, force update, setting the State in the DbEntry .

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I debugged a little further, and looks like the line databaseContext.SaveChanges() never returns (neither asynchronous or synchronous)

Comment: Could it be a transaction deadlock?

Comment: Can't you monitor the SQL by adding a ctx.Database.Log += Console.WriteLine?